# Compressing a perfect sheet of metal. How will it fold?

Tags: forces

Suppose a sheet of metal is compressed with equal force on both sides. In the presence of no other external force acting on the sheet how will it fold? Will It fold upwards or downwards or in a sine wave like pattern? What determines the pattern of folding?

Comment: You are describing buckling; this would not be likely for a sheet of metal under compression. Buckling occurs on unconstrained surfaces.

Comment: @PeterDiehr is correct - under hydrostatic compression there is no buckling. If it is not hydrostatic you need to specify.

Comment: A sheet has six sides, which two are you talking about? Can you include a sketch or a better description?

Answer (score 0):

It depends its lengh and how you fix it at both end. If it is simply stuck between perpendicual planes, it will bend upward or downward (1/2 chance).